# VBA code to clear all slicer filters and select

Tags: vba

I have a very simple VBA code where I want to first clear all filters in the slicer then select RB.

Below is the code I am using without success:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Manufacturer1").ClearManualFilter    
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Manufacturer1")
.SlicerItems("RB").Selected = True
End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know what happens:

```
Dim cache As SlicerCache 

For Each cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches 
 cache.ClearManualFilter 
Next cache

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Manufacturer1")
.SlicerItems("RB").Selected = True
End With
End Sub
```